# Xcode 15 Mergeable Library

Tags: xcode15, xcode-mergeable-libraries

Xcode 15 introduces something called Mergeable Libraries, where release builds that have direct dependencies on dylibs or frameworks are merged into the final executable. (This happens iff the project is configured correctly. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/configuring-your-project-to-use-mergeable-libraries).)

I've got a configured Xcode 15 project with two targets, one is a dynamic library and another is a command line binary. The latter one depends on the first (the lib is a target dependency and it's listed in the `Link binary with libraries` thing under `Build Phases`). Also:

- The library has been configured with the option `Build Mergeable Library` set to `YES`
- The binary has been configured with `Create Merged Binary` set to `Automatic`

Still, nothing is merged and the binary does not work if the `*.dylib` is not available. I would have guessed that "merging" means merging into the binary, but maybe not.

Also, a library where the `merge` option has been turned on should have additional metadata of some sort in it, but in my case turning on/off the option does not seems to add/remove anything from the `*.dylib` (according to vimdiff, at least).

Has anyone tried this and made it work?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it should work at least for your first dependency, which is a direct dependency.

When you say your dependency is a "dynamic library", I believe it's a dynamic framework? and merging happens in release mode, to verify if your dependency is being merged or not, you can inspect symbols on your main app binary.

Run `nm -j //path-to-app-binary | grep <any-class-from-your-dependency>`, this should show some results.

if you need more details, you can checkout my article on this - https://medium.com/@SanjuNaik14/meet-mergeable-libraries-790a40aa89b8